# module is duplicated using webpack

Tags: webpack

I am recently switching to webpack for my project ( Angularjs 1, AdminLTE, SPA ).

There are login page and after login pages.
For the login page, I demand jquery, bootstrap, angular etc,
For the after login pages, I demand all of the above plus datatables, moment etc.

so I setup my webpack.config like

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const basepath = 'resources/assets/js/angular/';
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}
        ],
        noParse: [/moment-with-locales/]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        common: ['jquery','bootstrap', 'fastclick', 'sparklines', 'slimscroll','angular','angular-route', 'oclazyload', 'angular-translate', path.resolve(__dirname, `${basepath}../adminlte/adminlte.js`)],
        angular: [path.resolve(__dirname, `${basepath}app.js`), path.resolve(__dirname, `${basepath}service.js`)],
        login: path.resolve(__dirname, `${basepath}ctrl/login.js`),
        logined: ['datatables.net', 'angular-datatables', 'moment', 'ui-select', 'angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker', path.resolve(__dirname, `${basepath}app2.js`)]            
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
            moment: "moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["common"],
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            moment: "moment"
        })            
    ]
};
```

But the above config will result in duplication of moment's code in generated logined.js and angular.js
It may be because I have called moment in angular.module().run() in app.js
So the dependency is injected to the produced angular.js

What I want is the moment being included in logined.js and I can use it everywhere (for after login pages).

For the login page I will include common.js, 
and after login pages I will include common.js plus logined.js

I don't know if my concept is wrong, I am new to webpack.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What webpack will do? It will bundle every thing into one file as configured in your webpack.config so every thing you bundle will be available in your application. Instead of requiring moment from webpack let your application handle it and it should be bundled only once or just use the plugin and remove moment from entries.